A more efficient way to add values inplace at colums of a 2d matrix, using a 2d array for the colum indices
I would like to do a += operation at specified columns of a 2d matrix, where the column indices are in another 2D matrix.
Specifically, is there a more efficient way to do the operation in loop_fun below.
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)

N, V, D, B = 5, 25000, 300, 512
grad = np.zeros((D, V))

# col_idx columns and rows can have duplicate indices, so 
# as += applied at the vector level leads to only a single 
# instance of the index working.
col_idx = np.random.randint(0, V-1, size=(N, B))

# force at least one example of duplicates within a column.
col_idx[:, 0] = np.array([0, 100, V-1, 0, V-1])

values = np.random.normal(size=(D, B))

def loop_fun(grad_mat, col_mat, val_mat):
    for b in range(col_mat.shape[1]):
        for row in range(col_mat.shape[0]):
            grad_mat[:, col_mat[row, b]] += val_mat[:, b]
    return grad_mat

def loop_fun_wrong(grad_mat, col_mat, val_mat):
    # This fails because += only applies the 
    # last instance of a duplicated index.
    for b in range(col_mat.shape[1]):
        grad_mat[:, col_mat[:, b]] += val_mat[:, b, np.newaxis]
    return grad_mat

grad = loop_fun(grad, col_idx, values)
grad_wrong = loop_fun_wrong(np.zeros_like(grad), col_idx, values)
#  Unfortunately the inner loop is required!
print(f'{np.allclose(grad, grad_wrong)=}')  # False

np.add.at is supposed to be useful when += doesn't work, but couldn't quite figure out how to use it in this case.

Your example gives: IndexError: index 25000 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 25000

Please provide a non random [mre] with explanations

Sorry, fixed the error. Max index is V-1 for dimension length of V.

@Julien, added the random seed.

Figured out how to implement np.add.at for this use case.
You have to broadcast every single index element. For example, for the 10'th column to be modified, you have to create a Dx2 array representing every elements row & col index for the 10'th column:
[[0, 1, 2, ..., 298, 300],
[10, 10, 10, ..., 10, 10]]

And you have to do that for every entry in col_idx which is shape=(N, B). So you have an index tuple (rows, cols) of shape: ((N, D, B), (N, D, B))
def add_at_fun(grad_mat, col_mat, val_mat):
    shp = (col_mat.shape[0], grad_mat.shape[0], val_mat.shape[1])  # shp: (5, 300, 512)
    row_idx = np.broadcast_to(np.arange(grad_mat.shape[0])[:, np.newaxis], shape=shp)
    col_idx = np.broadcast_to(col_mat[:, np.newaxis, :], shape=shp)
    np.add.at(grad_mat, (row_idx, col_idx), val_mat)
    return grad_mat

grad_add_at = add_at_fun(np.zeros_like(grad), col_idx, values)
print(f'{np.allclose(grad, grad_add_at)=}')  # True

Unfortunately, it takes about 3.5x slower on the examples in this question. So might be more readable, but definitely isn't more efficient.
%timeit loop_fun(grad, col_idx, values)
%timeit loop_fun_wrong(grad, col_idx, values)
%timeit add_at_fun(grad, col_idx, values)
8.94 ms ± 455 μs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
11.2 ms ± 232 μs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
35.3 ms ± 2.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

